# Python accessing existing variable using string names

Tags: python, function, object

I'm trying to design a python function(function_A) which receives two inputs;

Basically, what I'm trying to do is parsing important part from a received sentence(input name : 'sent') according to its type (input name : 'check')

Types are 20 kinds and I have a regular expression for each of them.

For example, if the type of sentence(i.e. check) is 2, it should use regular expression named c2 for parsing sentence;

For example,

```
c2 = re.compile('(?:sale|sold|provide).*?\sto\s(.*)', re.I|re.S)
```

(So I have 20 regular expressions, from c1 to c20)

For the summary, if this function receives `type(check)` 'n' then, it uses c'n' to parse the sentence.

So, What I've tried up to now is like below:

```
def newpythonfunction(sent, check):
    c1 = re.compile(~~~)
    c2 = re.compile(~~!@!)
    .....
    c20 = re.compile(!@!@!#!#)
    c_check = 'c' + str(check)
    return c_check.findall(sent)
```

however, as you might already expect, since `c_check` is a string, it cannot work as c'n'...

I know I can use 20 if sentences to deal with,

however, I wonder if there any better and efficient(at least just for me writing code) way to make it work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `locals()['c{}'.format(check)]`, but it's better if you just organize your expressions in a proper data structure, like a list or a dict:

```
c = [
    re.compile(...),
    re.compile(...),
    ...
]
c_check = c[check - 1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I first thought about making dictionary, however, it would be great! Thanks!